# How to fetch data based on Foreign Key in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables. Table1 and table2.

> Table1 - fieldmapping
>
> Id(pk), FormField, SFields, Sobject
>
> Table2 -formfieldmapping
>
> form_number and form_id(fk).

When I inserted data using csv file into table1 then values are inserted into table2 as well with form number in form number field and Id in field_id field. When I duplicate value is inserted then in table1 it should not be inserted it should go to table 2 with form number and reference of table 1 ("Id"). Please Help.

```
<?php
error_reporting( E_ALL );
if(isset($_POST["Import"]))
{
$host="localhost"; 
$db_user="root";
$db_password="password";
$db='excel'; 
$conn=mysql_connect($host,$db_user,$db_password,$db) or die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($db) or die (mysql_error());

echo $filename=$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];

 if($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 0)
 {

  $file = fopen($filename, "r");
   while (($emapData = fgetcsv($file, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE)
   {
         $index=0;

        $query = "SELECT id FROM fieldmapping WHERE FormField ='$emapData[1]'";
    $result = mysql_query($query,$conn) or die(mysql_error());

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
             $index =$row["id"];
        $field=$row["fieldname"];

        }
        echo "index".$index;
        if($index <= 0){
            $sql = "INSERT into fieldmapping(FormField,SFField,SFObject) values('$emapData[1]','$emapData[2]','$emapData[3]')";
echo $sql;
        mysql_query($sql);
        $index=  $conn->insert_id;
        echo "last =".$index;
     }
    if(!$index){
    //$sql = "INSERT into formfieldmapping(form_number) values(1)";
    $sql = "INSERT into formfieldmapping(form_number)values('$emapData[0]')";
        mysql_query($sql); 
    }
else
{
//$sql = "INSERT into formfieldmapping(form_number,field_id) values(1,$index)";
$sql = "INSERT into formfieldmapping(form_number,field_id)values('$emapData[0]',$index)";
mysql_query($sql); 
}
        //mysql_query($sql);
echo $sql;
echo "<br>";
    

  }
    echo "CSV File has been successfully Imported";
}
    else
    {
     echo "Invalid File:Please Upload CSV File";
    }
  } 
   fclose($file);
mysql_close($conn);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Import CSV/Excel file</title>
</head>
<body>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
<table border="1" width="40%" align="center">
<tr >
<td colspan="2" align="center"><strong>Import CSV/Excel file</strong></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td align="center">CSV/Excel File:</td><td><input type="file" name="file" id="file"></td></tr>
<tr >
<td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" name="Import" value="Import"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL + PHP: fetching data using foreign keys](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3489017/mysql-php-fetching-data-using-foreign-keys)

Comment: what is primary key in table 2?

Comment: @ kamlesh.bar There is no primary key in table2